Unitary similarity to upper triangular matrix with nonnegative (1, 1) entry
This is Problem 11.12(b) from Matrix Mathematics: A Second Course in Linear Algebra by Garcia and Horn (which I am self-studying through).

Let $A \in \mathsf{M}_2$. Show that $A$ is unitarily similar to an upper triangular matrix with a real nonnegative entry in position $(1, 1)$.

My attempt: We know by Schur's Triangularization Theorem that $A$ is unitarily similar to an upper triangular matrix $T$ whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ (for this, write $A = UTU^\ast$). What remains is to find another $2 \times 2$ unitary matrix $V$ such that $VTV^\ast$ is upper triangular and has a real nonnegative entry in its $(1, 1)$ position. Write
\begin{equation*}
   T = \begin{bmatrix}
      \lambda_1 & \star \\
      0 & \lambda_2
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $T$. The text then suggests as a hint to use a diagonal similarity matrix for $V$; for example, we try
\begin{equation*}
V = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and see that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \star \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-i\theta} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \star \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
regardless of $\theta$. We thus cannot make the $(1, 1)$ entry positive using a unitary, diagonal matrix as our similarity matrix. When trying to work with non-diagonal unitary matrices, things become a lot more complicated, as the value of the $(1, 1)$ entry starts to depend on the value of the entry "$\star$", which Schur's Theorem (as stated) gives us no information about.
Any direction is appreciated, and generalization from $\mathsf{M}_2$ to $\mathsf{M}_n$ is also welcome.
Edit: Just after writing this, I've realized the claim as written above (directly transcribed from the text) to be false. As a counterexample, consider the scalar matrix $A = iI_2$, which is only similar (and hence unitarily similar) to itself, and doesn't have a real nonnegative $(1,1)$ entry. Does the claim in the problem hold for non-scalar matrices, however?
